# How to handle parameters right in c#?

Tags: c#

I just started using c# again and now I have a strange problem with my parameters.
I tried to build a List by my self.
So I have:

```
    class NodeList
    {
            public Node FirstCity { get; set; }

            public Node findNode(String name)
            {
                 //...stuff
            }
    }
```

And This:

```
class Node
{
   public String Name {get; set;}
   public Node next {get; set;}
}
```

So, in my project I (lets say on button click) create a new Nodelist.
(By default I have already a few nodes in it.)

Now I do this:

```
Node n = nodelist.findNode("test");
```

and then I have another class I called tool.

```
tool.doSomething(n , nodelist);
```

Now the strange thing is that, when I look at nodelist, when I call the above the list is correct. The doSomething method, doesn´t even call the nodelist but it changes it.

```
doSomething(n, list)
{
    NodeList nl = new NodeList();
    nl.Add(n);
    //other stuff
}
```

At the point where I change the new List for some reason the other list, which is in a different class, changes too.

Can anyone please explain why and how I can fix this!?

Edit:
This is my Add Method:

```
Add(Node node){
node.next = null;
            Node current = FirstCity;
            if (current == null)
                FirstCity = node;
            else
            {
                while (current.next != null)
                {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                current.next = node;
            }
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what your problem is. Anyway if a `Node` has a `Next` property, obviously you can't use one node in two lists as the previous node from list 1 will point to this node that's now in list 2. You're passing nodes by reference. Probably what you mean to do is make a copy of the node. We may be able to help if you showed more, actual code.

Comment: Can we see your `Add` method?  Note that `n` is the _actual same node_, not a copy, so when you add it to the second list, you could well be taking everything in the list beyond it (as referenced with the `next` property) too.

Comment: "The doSomething methode, doesn´t even call the nodelist but it changes it." I do not understand the sentence. How could you call a class (i.e. a type)? Does something unexpected happen? If yes: What behaviour do you expect, and what do you observe?

Comment: "how I can fix this!?" In order to fix something we first need to understand what the problem is, and this was not clear at all from your question.